# Docstrings for static properties in boost::python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have added python bindings for core features of my c++ application, and I'm now going through trying to add docstrings everywhere so that I can auto-document the exposed python using sphinx.

It nearly works, but when I have static properties, (added using the add_static_property method) I am unable to override the docstring. An example of this is one of my properties that returns a float:

```
MyClass.static_property.__doc__
float(x) -> floating point number
```

When I am using the def method, or the property method, the final parameter allows me to add my docstring. Does anyone know why this can't be done for static properties? And is there any way to allow them?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Python does not support it because Python does not support it.  As specified in [PEP 257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring):

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a *module*, *function*, *class*, or *method definition*. Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.

A Python class attribute variable is a reference, and not an object in and of itself.  Hence, the reference does not have a `__doc__` attribute, but the object to which it refers may.  For example, consider the following:

```python
>>> class Spam:
...     egg = 42
... 
>>> assert Spam.egg.__doc__ == int.__doc__
```

---

In Python, methods and [`property()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) are both objects, and thus may contain a docstring.  The Boost.Python [`boost::python::class_::add_static_property()`](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) function is a bit of a misnomer as Python does not have static properties.  The functional equivalent of a C++ static data member is Python's class variable.

As an alternative, consider documenting the class variables in the class docstring, as the documentation for the class variable is specific to the context of the containing class.  Here is a complete example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Mockup class.
struct spam
{
  static int egg;
  int parrot;
};

int spam::egg = 0;


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Documentation for this module.
  python::scope().attr("__doc__") = 
    ".. module:: example\n"
    "\n"
    "   :platform: Unix, Windows\n"
    "   :synopsis: An example module for Boost.Python docstrings.\n"
    "\n"
    ;

  const char* py_spam_doc =
    "A mockup ``Spam`` class.\n"
    "\n"
    "This class is just used for demonstrating docstrings.\n"
    "\n"
    ":cvar egg: The egg class variable's documentation.\n"
    "\n"
    ;
  python::class_<spam>("Spam", py_spam_doc)
    .add_property("parrot", &spam::parrot,
      "The parrot instance variable's documentation.")
    .add_static_property("egg",
      python::make_getter(&spam::egg),
      python::make_setter(&spam::egg))
    ;
}
```

After running `sphinx-quickstart` and enabling `autodoc`, modify the `index.rst` to include the desired Python components.  In this case, I added:

```
.. automodule:: example
   :noindex:

.. autoclass:: Spam
   :members:
```

And `make html` produced the following snippet:

[image: Boost.Python Sphinx docstring example]